# If field == null display else don't

Tags: php, mysqli, dreamweaver

My recordset is:

```
mysqli_select_db($KCC, $database_KCC);
$query_rsOtherServices = "SELECT pagecontent.mainMenuID, mainmenu.mainMenuLabel, pagecontent.subMenuID, submenu.subMenuLabel, pagecontent.contentID, pagecontent.contentTitle FROM submenu RIGHT JOIN (mainmenu RIGHT JOIN pagecontent ON mainmenu.mainMenuID = pagecontent.mainMenuID) ON submenu.subMenuID = pagecontent.subMenuID WHERE pagecontent.mainMenuID = 1 AND pagecontent.subMenuID IS NULL";
$rsOtherServices = mysqli_query($KCC, $query_rsOtherServices) or die(mysqli_error());
$row_rsOtherServices = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rsOtherServices);
$totalRows_rsOtherServices = mysqli_num_rows($rsOtherServices);
```

and the code I'm using to display the record is:

```
<?php do { ?>
<li><a href="familyservices.php?idVal=<?php echo $row_rsOtherServices['contentID']; ?>"><h4><?php echo $row_rsOtherServices['contentTitle']; ?></h4></a></li>
<?php } while ($row_rsOtherServices = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rsOtherServices)); ?>
```

This all works fine if a record exists but if there is no record, a 'link' is available to click even though it's not visible.

I have tried `<?php if ($totalRows_rsOtherServices['subMenuID'] === Null) { ?>`, `<?php if ($totalRows_rsOtherServices['subMenuID'] > 0) { ?>`, `<?php if ($totalRows_rsOtherServices['subMenuID'] == true) { ?>`, `<?php if ($totalRows_rsOtherServices['subMenuID'] == false) { ?>`but to no avail.

I know nothing about programming and even less about PHP so I'm not even sure is I'm going in the right direction.

I need to get rid of the 'invisible link'.

Answer (score 3):

Because you are using `do ... while`, use `while` only.

Try

```
<?php while (($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rsOtherServices))) { ?>
    <li>
        <a href="familyservices.php?idVal=<?php echo $row['contentID']; ?>">
            <h4><?php echo $row['contentTitle']; ?></h4>
        </a>
    </li>
<? } ?>
```

Comment: Correct. Maybe add the code of how the `foreach` would look like.

Comment: sorry, but i think while only is the correct one, try it.

Comment: If I use this, it displays nothing even if there is a record to display. In fact, I get an error because of the `<? } ?>` in the last line. If I change it to `<?php } ?>` the error is removed.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've figured it out.

Instead of using `$((totalRows_rsOtherServices['subMenuID']) > 0)`, I changed it to `(($row_rsOtherServices) > 0)`. This did the trick.

However, if I use the `while (($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rsOtherServices)))...` as suggested, even if there is a record, it doesn't display.

At this moment in time I'm not going to worry to much about that but will investigate it in the future.